# How to integrate IKVM with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ikvm

We have a strategic decision to migrate our project from JAVA to C#. Instead of waiting for a completed migration, we want to pack most of our Java code into .dll and quickly get the project up and run with a C# framework that uses these .dlls. And then we can gradually convert the rest of Java code to C#.

We are considering IKVM and we know with its ikvmc command, we can actually turn .class to .dll.  but it's quite tedious to manually type in command. Is there a way to let Eclipse integrated with IKVM and generate the .dlls while generating .class?

Answer (score 0):

Use ikvmc as part of an ant build: see http://ant-ikvmc.sourceforge.net/